# Why does my Access VBA to add subtotals in Excel work in one database but error 1004 in another?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, subtotal

I am new to VBA and using Access to run a query and save the results as a spreadsheet on a local drive. Once saved, Access opens the Excel file and adds subtotal rows and some basic formatting.  This works fine in my sandbox database.  When I copy and paste the same code into the production database (along with the query and macro), I get this error message:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNOWc.jpg)

```
Public Sub autoformat()
wkbookpath = "H:\1401_by_division.xls"
Dim XL As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set XL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If XL Is Nothing Then
  Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If

With XL
    .Visible = True
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .Workbooks.Open wkbookpath
        .Range("1:1").Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
'       .Range("A2").Activate
        .Range("A1").Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(4, 5, 6, 7, _
          8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21), Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, _
          SummaryBelowData:=True
    .Range("U:U").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    .Range("1:1").WrapText = True
     .Columns("A:U").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With     
End Sub
```

Here is an example of the spreadsheet I'm trying to subtotal.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYKLv.jpg)

Am I not properly referencing the active sheet? That is the only thing I can think of that would explain functioning in one database and then not in another--they are exact copies of each other.

Help!

Comment: Try to create a minimal example. Remove all unnecessary comments

Comment: It looks like all your `.Range` objects are trying to act on the application (XL variable) rather than a specific worksheet in the opened workbook.  Create a workbook variable (object type if in Access) and open the workbook with it `Set wrkbk = .Workbooks.Open(.....)`, then use `With wrkbk.worksheets("SheetName")` and then the `.Range` code.

Comment: Are you sure that the worksheet has data?  Excel will also complain if cannot determine if the data has column headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your sandbox database actually has an Excel reference and the production database doesn't.  Even though the *code* is late bound in both of them, you're using `xlSum`, which is a member of the `Excel.XlConsolidationFunction` enumeration.

The ***only*** way this would work in your sandbox is if the enumeration can be resolved or you're setting it as a constant somewhere.  The fact that it compiles in your production database also indicates that you don't have `Option Explicit` specified in the module (get in the habit of always adding it to avoid this in the future).  Otherwise you'd get a compiler error that highlights it. If it isn't declared, it's being treated as an uninitialized `Variant`, which casts to `0` and throws a 1004 when passed as the `Function` argument.

If you're late bound without a reference, either use the numeric value of `xlSum` (-4157)...

```
.Range("A1").Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=-4157, TotalList:=Array(4, 5, 6, 7, _
  8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21), Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, _
  SummaryBelowData:=True
```

...or declare it as a constant somewhere:

```
Public Const xlSum As Long = -4157
```

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. Comintern, your suggestion of switching to the numeric value caused it to run the first time and then error the second time on my wkbkpath variable. I omitted that and opened it directly with the .Workbooks.Open ("H:\1401_by_division.xls").  I think that Darren is correct also--I am working on the Excel object rather than the specific spreadsheet. I am going to work on that today and may come back with follow up questions.